# Rxjs/Ngrx Filtering Stream based on a property from another stream

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx

I am having problems understanding and getting something to work with RxJS Observables and ngrx Store.

I have tried `combineLatest`, filters, concatenating arrays etc but can’t seem to get a working bug free solution.

I would appreciate any comments / feedback on which techniques would be best to achieve this result

#### Requirement

1. Take 2 Objects from ngrx Store and filter the first Object by a
   property in the second Object

   - People - 1st Object List of People
   - Companies - 2nd Object List of Companies
   - PeopleFromSelectedCompanies - Filter 1st Object to only show
     people that match the Company Id’s in the second Object d.  If no
     companies exist in 2nd Object then I want to show all people from 01st Object
2. Assign PeopleFromSelectedCompanies to DataSource for Angular Material DataTable
3. Accept a string filter to filter the PeopleFromSelectedCompanies for any properties that contain the string

All of the `ngOnInit` code works fine I get access to all the lists required and each time I select another customer the `getSelectedCustomersPeople` runs.
Current spaghetti code  if you can understand what I am trying to do

#### Component

```typescript
ngOnInit() {
  this.peopleStore.dispatch(new fromPeopleStore.LoadPeople());

  this.people$ = this.peopleStore.select(fromPeopleStore.getAllPeople);

  this.selectedCustomers$ = this.toolbarStore
    .select(fromToolbarStore.getSelectedCustomers);

  this.selectedCustomers$.subscribe(selected => {
    this.selectedCustomersPeople$ = this.getSelectedCustomersPeople();
  });
}

getSelectedCustomersPeople(): Observable<Person[]> {
  return combineLatest(this.selectedCustomers$, this.people$, (customers, people) => {
    const allSelectedPeople = customers.map(
      customer => Object.assign(people.filter(
        person => person.company === customer.id
      ))
    );

    const flattenSelectedPeople = [].concat.apply([], allSelectedPeople);

    return flattenSelectedPeople;
  });
}

applyFilter(filterValue = ' ') {
  filterValue = filterValue.trim();
  filterValue = filterValue.toLowerCase();
  this.selectedCustomersPeople$ = filterValue;
  // Would like to filter here not sure how
}
```

#### Template

```html
<mat-table #table [dataSource]="selectedCustomersPeople$ | async"
  matSort
  [@animateStagger]="{ value: '50' }">
  <!-- Name Column -->
  <ng-container cdkColumnDef="firstName">
    <mat-header-cell *cdkHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>First Name</mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *cdkCellDef="let person">
      <p class="text-truncate font-weight-600">
        {{ person.firstName }} {{ person.familyName }}
      </p>
    </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>

  <mat-header-row *cdkHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
  <mat-row *cdkRowDef="let person; columns: displayedColumns;"
    class="person"
    (click)="editPerson(person)"
    [ngClass]="{'mat-light-blue-50-bg': checkboxes[person.id]}"
    matRipple
    [@animate]="{ value: '*', params: { y: '100%' } }">
  </mat-row>
</mat-table>
```

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else is trying to do something similar, I got a working solution.  Updated Code below, might not be best or cleanest way to do it but it works nicely:

```
constructor(
    private peopleStore: Store<fromPeopleStore.PeopleState>,
    private toolbarStore: Store<fromToolbarStore.CustomerState>,
    public dialog: MatDialog
  ) {
    this.peopleStore.dispatch(new fromPeopleStore.LoadPeople());
    this.people$ = this.peopleStore.select(fromPeopleStore.getAllPeople);
    this.selectedCustomers$ = this.toolbarStore.select(fromToolbarStore.getSelectedCustomers);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.selectedCustomers$.subscribe(selected => {
      if (selected.length !== 0) {
        this.selectedCustomersPeople$ = this.getSelectedCustomersPeople();
        this.selectedCustomersPeople$.subscribe(people => {
          this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(people);
          this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
          this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
        });
      } else {
        this.people$.subscribe(people => {
          this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(people);
          this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
          this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
        });
      }
    });
  }

  getSelectedCustomersPeople(): Observable<Person[]> {
    return combineLatest(this.selectedCustomers$, this.people$, (customers, people) => {
      const selectedCustomersPeople = customers.map(customer =>
        Object.assign(people.filter(person => person.companyId === customer.id))
      );
      const flattenSelectedPeople = [].concat.apply([], selectedCustomersPeople);

      return flattenSelectedPeople;
    });
  }

  applyFilter(filterValue = ' ') {
    filterValue = filterValue.trim();
    filterValue = filterValue.toLowerCase();
    this.dataSource.filter = filterValue;
  }

<mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort [@animateStagger]="{value:'50'}">

    <!-- Name Column -->
    <ng-container cdkColumnDef="firstName">
        <mat-header-cell *cdkHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>First Name</mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *cdkCellDef="let person">
            <p class="text-truncate font-weight-600">{{person.firstName}} {{person.familyName}}</p>
        </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <mat-header-row *cdkHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
    <mat-row *cdkRowDef="let person; columns: displayedColumns;" class="person" (click)="editPerson(person)" [ngClass]="{'mat-light-blue-50-bg':checkboxes[person.id]}"
        matRipple [@animate]="{value:'*',params:{y:'100%'}}">
    </mat-row>
</mat-table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I did a basic example on how to do it a bit cleaner by working with the rx streams.

I did a basic standalone example where I created two sources (customers$ and companies$) which will emit all 0.8 - 1 seconds. This was just so I could test this locally. You should be able to do the same using the people$ and selectedCompanies$ observables.

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/interval';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/combineLatest';

interface Customer {
    id: number;
    company: number;
}

interface Company {
    id: number;
}

export function test() {
    // Emits a customer list all 1000 milliseconds
    const customers$: Observable<Customer[]> = Observable
        .interval(1000)
        .map(() => <Customer[]>[{ id: 1, company: 1}, {id: 2, company: 1}, {id: 3, company: 5}]);
    // Emits a company list all 800 milliseconds
    const companies$: Observable<Customer[]> = Observable
        .interval(800)
        .map(() => <Customer[]>[{ id: 1, company: 1}, {id: 2, company: 1}]);

    // Create a stream that combines the latest value of both lists
    const both$ = Observable.combineLatest(customers$, companies$);

    // Create a new observable which will emit the filtered customers
    const filteredCustomers$ = both$.map((data: any) => {
        const customers: Customer[] = data[0];
        const companies: Company[] = data[1];
        // We did not receive any companies, so we can return the full customer list
        if (!companies || companies.length === 0) {
            return customers;
        }

        // Create an object that will have keys of existing companies as id
        const companyIds = {};
        companies.forEach(c => companyIds[c.id] = true);

        // Return the filtered version of the customers
        return customers
            // In the filter statement, we check if the company id exists
            // in our helper object. You could leave out the "=== true" part.
            .filter(customer => companyIds[customer.company] === true);
    });

    // Now we have a filteredCustomers$ observable where we can subscribe:
    filteredCustomers$.subscribe(customers => console.log('Filtered Customers: ', customers));
}
```